# Do I need to glue doweled joints in MDF?

Tags: joinery

I am making a cupboard unit using melamine faced MDF. The joints will be made using wood dowels. My question is do I use glue as well and if so which sort?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Dowels are good for lining up boards when assembling joints and for keeping them from slipping. They're not so good for holding pieces together long term - that's where the glue comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes- use a good wood glue such as any of the Titebond line or Gorilla wood glue.  All are of sufficient holding power for your dowel joints.  The MDF will give away before the joint breaks apart.